# Reset date.timezone in php.ini, still won't work

Tags: php

So I'm trying to run a php file and I get this error:

> Warning: date_default_timezone_get(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/Los_Angeles' for 'PDT/-7.0/DST' instead...

Basically, I need to set the default date.timzeone variable in the configuration file.
Upon running php -info, I find that the conf file is located here:

Configuration File (php.ini) Path => `/opt/local/etc/php5`

So I navigate to that folder and find no `php.ini` file, instead a `php.ini-development` and a `php.ini-production`. In both, I set date.timezone="America/Los_Angeles" and copy one of them and name it php.ini. Still no dice. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: rename one of them to `php.ini` remove the suffix

Comment: That's what I did ^^, renamed one to php.ini as I mentioned.

Comment: Try to look at `Loaded Configuration File` value in your phpinfo

Comment: Did you try restarting the Apache server?

Comment: check `phpinfo()` it'll tell you what file(s) were loaded, and where from. then remember to restart apache after changing the files.

Comment: Loaded Configuration file had ==> (none). I killed the server after each edit to php.ini.

Comment: This may help to find out where 'apache' is looking for php.ini and why it cannot find it [manual/en/configuration.file.php](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php)

Answer (score 0):

i found that editing the cli php ini file fixed my issue for the default timezone:

```
 /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```